# FFMPEG Output File is Empty Nothing was Encoded (for a Picture)?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have a strange issue effecting one of my programs that does bulk media conversions using ffmpeg from the command line, however this effects me using it directly from the shell as well:

`ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv -ss 0:30 -y -qscale:v 2 -frames:v 1 -f image2 -huffman optimal "OUTPUT.png"`
fails every run with the error message:
`Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)`

This only happens with very specific videos, and seemingly no other videos. File type is usually .webm. These files have been downloaded properly (usually from yt-dlp), and I have tried re-downloading them just to verify their integrity.

One such file from a colleague was: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xkucr2z5ra1p2oh/Triggerheart%20Execlica%20OST%20%28Arrange%29%20-%20Crueltear%20Ending.mkv?dl=0

Is there a subtle issue with the command string?

**Notes:**

removing `-huffman optimal` had no effect

moving `-ss` to before `-i` had no effect

removing `-f image2 had no effect`

**Full Log:**

```
sarah@MidnightStarSign:~/Music/Playlists/Indexing/Indexing Temp$ ffmpeg -i Triggerheart\ Execlica\ OST\ \(Arrange\)\ -\ Crueltear\ Ending.mkv -ss 0:30 -y -qscale:v 2 -frames:v 1 -f image2 -huffman optimal "TEST.png"
ffmpeg version n5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-vulkan
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
[matroska,webm @ 0x55927f484740] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Attachment: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Triggerheart Execlica OST (Arrange) - Crueltear Ending.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : TriggerHeart Exelica PS2 & 360 Arrange ー 16 - Crueltear Ending
    PURL            : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJ0bEa_8xEg
    COMMENT         : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJ0bEa_8xEg
    ARTIST          : VinnyVynce
    DATE            : 20170905
    ENCODER         : Lavf59.27.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 430 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 720x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:29.934000000
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:30.001000000
  Stream #0:2: Attachment: none
    Metadata:
      filename        : cover.webp
      mimetype        : image/webp
Codec AVOption huffman (Huffman table strategy) specified for output file #0 (TEST.png) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to 'TEST.png':
  Metadata:
    title           : TriggerHeart Exelica PS2 & 360 Arrange ー 16 - Crueltear Ending
    PURL            : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJ0bEa_8xEg
    COMMENT         : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJ0bEa_8xEg
    ARTIST          : VinnyVynce
    DATE            : 20170905
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: png, rgb24, 720x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:29.934000000
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 png
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

Manjaro OS System Specs:

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.1.12-1-MANJARO arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 12.2.1
    parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/@/boot/vmlinuz-6.1-x86_64
    root=UUID=f11386cf-342d-47ac-84e6-484b7b2f377d rw rootflags=subvol=@
    radeon.modeset=1 nvdia-drm.modeset=1 quiet
    cryptdevice=UUID=059df4b4-5be4-44d6-a23a-de81135eb5b4:luks-disk
    root=/dev/mapper/luks-disk apparmor=1 security=apparmor
    resume=/dev/mapper/luks-swap udev.log_priority=3
  Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.26.5 tk: Qt v: 5.15.8 wm: kwin_x11 vt: 1 dm: SDDM
    Distro: Manjaro Linux base: Arch Linux
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: PRIME X570-PRO v: Rev X.0x
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 4408
    date: 10/27/2022
Battery:
  Message: No system battery data found. Is one present?
Memory:
  RAM: total: 62.71 GiB used: 27.76 GiB (44.3%)
  RAM Report: permissions: Unable to run dmidecode. Root privileges required.
CPU:
  Info: model: AMD Ryzen 9 5950X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3+ gen: 4
    level: v3 note: check built: 2022 process: TSMC n6 (7nm) family: 0x19 (25)
    model-id: 0x21 (33) stepping: 0 microcode: 0xA201016
  Topology: cpus: 1x cores: 16 tpc: 2 threads: 32 smt: enabled cache:
    L1: 1024 KiB desc: d-16x32 KiB; i-16x32 KiB L2: 8 MiB desc: 16x512 KiB
    L3: 64 MiB desc: 2x32 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 4099 high: 4111 min/max: 2200/6358 boost: disabled
    scaling: driver: acpi-cpufreq governor: schedutil cores: 1: 4099 2: 4095
    3: 4102 4: 4100 5: 4097 6: 4100 7: 4110 8: 4111 9: 4083 10: 4099 11: 4100
    12: 4094 13: 4097 14: 4101 15: 4100 16: 4099 17: 4100 18: 4097 19: 4098
    20: 4095 21: 4100 22: 4099 23: 4099 24: 4105 25: 4098 26: 4100 27: 4100
    28: 4092 29: 4103 30: 4101 31: 4100 32: 4099 bogomips: 262520
  Flags: 3dnowprefetch abm adx aes aperfmperf apic arat avic avx avx2 bmi1
    bmi2 bpext cat_l3 cdp_l3 clflush clflushopt clwb clzero cmov cmp_legacy
    constant_tsc cpb cpuid cqm cqm_llc cqm_mbm_local cqm_mbm_total
    cqm_occup_llc cr8_legacy cx16 cx8 de decodeassists erms extapic
    extd_apicid f16c flushbyasid fma fpu fsgsbase fsrm fxsr fxsr_opt ht
    hw_pstate ibpb ibrs ibs invpcid irperf lahf_lm lbrv lm mba mca mce
    misalignsse mmx mmxext monitor movbe msr mtrr mwaitx nonstop_tsc nopl npt
    nrip_save nx ospke osvw overflow_recov pae pat pausefilter pclmulqdq
    pdpe1gb perfctr_core perfctr_llc perfctr_nb pfthreshold pge pku pni popcnt
    pse pse36 rapl rdpid rdpru rdrand rdseed rdt_a rdtscp rep_good sep sha_ni
    skinit smap smca smep ssbd sse sse2 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 stibp succor
    svm svm_lock syscall tce topoext tsc tsc_scale umip v_spec_ctrl
    v_vmsave_vmload vaes vgif vmcb_clean vme vmmcall vpclmulqdq wbnoinvd wdt
    x2apic xgetbv1 xsave xsavec xsaveerptr xsaveopt xsaves
  Vulnerabilities:
  Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected
  Type: l1tf status: Not affected
  Type: mds status: Not affected
  Type: meltdown status: Not affected
  Type: mmio_stale_data status: Not affected
  Type: retbleed status: Not affected
  Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via
    prctl
  Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer
    sanitization
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Retpolines, IBPB: conditional, IBRS_FW,
    STIBP: always-on, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS: Not affected
  Type: srbds status: Not affected
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA104 [GeForce RTX 3070] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia
    v: 525.89.02 alternate: nouveau,nvidia_drm non-free: 525.xx+
    status: current (as of 2023-02) arch: Ampere code: GAxxx
    process: TSMC n7 (7nm) built: 2020-22 pcie: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 8
    link-max: lanes: 16 bus-ID: 0b:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:2484 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: AMD Cape Verde PRO [Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E]
    vendor: VISIONTEK driver: radeon v: kernel alternate: amdgpu arch: GCN-1
    code: Southern Islands process: TSMC 28nm built: 2011-20 pcie: gen: 3
    speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 8 link-max: lanes: 16 ports: active: DP-3,DP-4
    empty: DP-1, DP-2, DP-5, DP-6 bus-ID: 0c:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:683f
    class-ID: 0300 temp: 54.0 C
  Device-3: Microdia USB 2.0 Camera type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 9-2:3 chip-ID: 0c45:6367 class-ID: 0102 serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8
    compositor: kwin_x11 driver: X: loaded: modesetting,nvidia dri: radeonsi
    gpu: radeon display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 5760x2160 s-dpi: 80 s-size: 1829x686mm (72.01x27.01")
    s-diag: 1953mm (76.91")
  Monitor-1: DP-1 pos: 1-2 res: 1920x1080 dpi: 93
    size: 527x296mm (20.75x11.65") diag: 604mm (23.8") modes: N/A
  Monitor-2: DP-1-3 pos: 2-1 res: 1920x1080 dpi: 82
    size: 598x336mm (23.54x13.23") diag: 686mm (27.01") modes: N/A
  Monitor-3: DP-1-4 pos: 1-1 res: 1920x1080 dpi: 93
    size: 527x296mm (20.75x11.65") diag: 604mm (23.8") modes: N/A
  Monitor-4: DP-3 pos: primary,2-2 res: 1920x1080 dpi: 82
    size: 598x336mm (23.54x13.23") diag: 686mm (27.01") modes: N/A
  Monitor-5: DP-4 pos: 2-4 res: 1920x1080 dpi: 82
    size: 598x336mm (23.54x13.23") diag: 686mm (27.01") modes: N/A
  Monitor-6: HDMI-0 pos: 1-3 res: 1920x1080 dpi: 93
    size: 527x296mm (20.75x11.65") diag: 604mm (23.8") modes: N/A
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.89.02 renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX
    3070/PCIe/SSE2 direct-render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA104 High Definition Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 5-1:2 v: kernel chip-ID: 30be:1019 pcie:
    class-ID: 0102 gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 8 link-max: lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 0b:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:228b class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000
    Series] vendor: VISIONTEK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: gen: 3
    speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 8 link-max: lanes: 16 bus-ID: 0c:00.1
    chip-ID: 1002:aab0 class-ID: 0403
  Device-3: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 0e:00.4 chip-ID: 1022:1487 class-ID: 0403
  Device-4: Schiit Audio Unison Universal Dac type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio
  Device-5: JMTek LLC. Plugable USB Audio Device type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 5-2:3 chip-ID: 0c76:120b
    class-ID: 0300 serial: <filter>
  Device-6: ASUSTek ASUS AI Noise-Cancelling Mic Adapter type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 5-4:4 chip-ID: 0b05:194e
    class-ID: 0300 serial: <filter>
  Device-7: Microdia USB 2.0 Camera type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 9-2:3 chip-ID: 0c45:6367 class-ID: 0102 serial: <filter>
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.1.12-1-MANJARO running: yes
  Sound Interface: sndio v: N/A running: no
  Sound Server-1: PulseAudio v: 16.1 running: no
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel I211 Gigabit Network vendor: ASUSTeK driver: igb v: kernel
    pcie: gen: 1 speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: f000 bus-ID: 07:00.0
    chip-ID: 8086:1539 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp7s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IP v4: <filter> type: dynamic noprefixroute scope: global
    broadcast: <filter>
  IP v6: <filter> type: noprefixroute scope: link
  IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IP v4: <filter> scope: global broadcast: <filter>
  WAN IP: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Cambridge Silicon Radio Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode) type: USB
    driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 5-5.3:7 chip-ID: 0a12:0001 class-ID: e001
  Report: rfkill ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: see --recommends
Logical:
  Message: No logical block device data found.
  Device-1: luks-c847cf9f-c6b5-4624-a25e-4531e318851a maj-min: 254:2
    type: LUKS dm: dm-2 size: 3.64 TiB
  Components:
  p-1: sda1 maj-min: 8:1 size: 3.64 TiB
  Device-2: luks-swap maj-min: 254:1 type: LUKS dm: dm-1 size: 12 GiB
  Components:
  p-1: nvme0n1p2 maj-min: 259:2 size: 12 GiB
  Device-3: luks-disk maj-min: 254:0 type: LUKS dm: dm-0 size: 919.01 GiB
  Components:
  p-1: nvme0n1p3 maj-min: 259:3 size: 919.01 GiB
RAID:
  Message: No RAID data found.
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 9.1 TiB used: 2.79 TiB (30.6%)
  SMART Message: Unable to run smartctl. Root privileges required.
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 maj-min: 259:0 vendor: Western Digital
    model: WDS100T3X0C-00SJG0 size: 931.51 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B
    logical: 512 B speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter>
    rev: 111110WD temp: 53.9 C scheme: GPT
  ID-2: /dev/nvme1n1 maj-min: 259:4 vendor: Western Digital
    model: WDS100T2B0C-00PXH0 size: 931.51 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B
    logical: 512 B speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter>
    rev: 211070WD temp: 46.9 C scheme: GPT
  ID-3: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Western Digital
    model: WD4005FZBX-00K5WB0 size: 3.64 TiB block-size: physical: 4096 B
    logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: HDD rpm: 7200 serial: <filter>
    rev: 1A01 scheme: GPT
  ID-4: /dev/sdb maj-min: 8:16 vendor: Western Digital
    model: WD4005FZBX-00K5WB0 size: 3.64 TiB block-size: physical: 4096 B
    logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: HDD rpm: 7200 serial: <filter>
    rev: 1A01 scheme: GPT
  ID-5: /dev/sdc maj-min: 8:32 type: USB vendor: SanDisk
    model: Gaming Xbox 360 size: 7.48 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B
    logical: 512 B type: N/A serial: <filter> rev: 8.02 scheme: MBR
  SMART Message: Unknown USB bridge. Flash drive/Unsupported enclosure?
  Message: No optical or floppy data found.
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw-size: 919.01 GiB size: 919.01 GiB (100.00%)
    used: 611.14 GiB (66.5%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/dm-0 maj-min: 254:0
    mapped: luks-disk label: N/A uuid: N/A
  ID-2: /boot/efi raw-size: 512 MiB size: 511 MiB (99.80%)
    used: 40.2 MiB (7.9%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 maj-min: 259:1 label: EFI
    uuid: 8922-E04D
  ID-3: /home raw-size: 919.01 GiB size: 919.01 GiB (100.00%)
    used: 611.14 GiB (66.5%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/dm-0 maj-min: 254:0
    mapped: luks-disk label: N/A uuid: N/A
  ID-4: /run/media/sarah/ConvergentRefuge raw-size: 3.64 TiB
    size: 3.64 TiB (100.00%) used: 2.19 TiB (60.1%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/dm-2
    maj-min: 254:2 mapped: luks-c847cf9f-c6b5-4624-a25e-4531e318851a
    label: ConvergentRefuge uuid: 7d295e73-4143-4eb1-9d22-75a06b1d2984
  ID-5: /run/media/sarah/MSS_EXtended raw-size: 475.51 GiB
    size: 475.51 GiB (100.00%) used: 1.48 GiB (0.3%) fs: btrfs
    dev: /dev/nvme1n1p1 maj-min: 259:5 label: MSS EXtended
    uuid: f98b3a12-e0e4-48c7-91c2-6e3aa6dcd32c
Swap:
  Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache-pressure: 100 (default)
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 12 GiB used: 6.86 GiB (57.2%)
    priority: -2 dev: /dev/dm-1 maj-min: 254:1 mapped: luks-swap label: SWAP
    uuid: c8991364-85a7-4e6c-8380-49cd5bd7a873
Unmounted:
  ID-1: /dev/nvme1n1p2 maj-min: 259:6 size: 456 GiB fs: ntfs label: N/A
    uuid: 5ECA358FCA356485
  ID-2: /dev/sdb1 maj-min: 8:17 size: 3.64 TiB fs: ntfs
    label: JerichoVariance uuid: 1AB22D5664889CBD
  ID-3: /dev/sdc1 maj-min: 8:33 size: 3.57 GiB fs: iso9660
  ID-4: /dev/sdc2 maj-min: 8:34 size: 4 MiB fs: vfat label: MISO_EFI
    uuid: 5C67-4BF8
USB:
  Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: Hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 4 rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-2: 1-2:2 info: Hitachi ports: 4 rev: 2.1 speed: 480 Mb/s
    chip-ID: 045b:0209 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 1-2.4:3 info: Microsoft Xbox One Controller (Firmware 2015)
    type: <vendor specific> driver: xpad interfaces: 3 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s
    power: 500mA chip-ID: 045e:02dd class-ID: ff00 serial: <filter>
  Hub-3: 2-0:1 info: Super-speed hub ports: 4 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0003 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-4: 2-2:2 info: Hitachi ports: 4 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s
    chip-ID: 045b:0210 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-5: 3-0:1 info: Hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 1 rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-6: 3-1:2 info: VIA Labs Hub ports: 4 rev: 2.1 speed: 480 Mb/s
    power: 100mA chip-ID: 2109:3431 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-7: 3-1.2:3 info: VIA Labs VL813 Hub ports: 4 rev: 2.1 speed: 480 Mb/s
    chip-ID: 2109:2813 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-8: 4-0:1 info: Super-speed hub ports: 4 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0003 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-9: 4-2:2 info: VIA Labs VL813 Hub ports: 4 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s
    chip-ID: 2109:0813 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-10: 5-0:1 info: Hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 6 rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 5-1:2 info: Schiit Audio Unison Universal Dac type: Audio
    driver: snd-usb-audio interfaces: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s power: 500mA
    chip-ID: 30be:1019 class-ID: 0102
  Device-2: 5-2:3 info: JMTek LLC. Plugable USB Audio Device type: Audio,HID
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid interfaces: 4 rev: 1.1
    speed: 12 Mb/s power: 100mA chip-ID: 0c76:120b class-ID: 0300
    serial: <filter>
  Device-3: 5-4:4 info: ASUSTek ASUS AI Noise-Cancelling Mic Adapter
    type: Audio,HID driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid interfaces: 4
    rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s power: 100mA chip-ID: 0b05:194e class-ID: 0300
    serial: <filter>
  Hub-11: 5-5:5 info: Genesys Logic Hub ports: 4 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
    power: 100mA chip-ID: 05e3:0608 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 5-5.3:7 info: Cambridge Silicon Radio Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
    type: Bluetooth driver: btusb interfaces: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s
    power: 100mA chip-ID: 0a12:0001 class-ID: e001
  Hub-12: 5-6:6 info: Genesys Logic Hub ports: 4 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
    power: 100mA chip-ID: 05e3:0608 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-13: 6-0:1 info: Super-speed hub ports: 4 rev: 3.1 speed: 10 Gb/s
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0003 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-14: 7-0:1 info: Hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 6 rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 7-2:2 info: SanDisk Cruzer Micro Flash Drive type: Mass Storage
    driver: usb-storage interfaces: 1 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s power: 200mA
    chip-ID: 0781:5151 class-ID: 0806 serial: <filter>
  Device-2: 7-4:3 info: ASUSTek AURA LED Controller type: HID
    driver: hid-generic,usbhid interfaces: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s power: 16mA
    chip-ID: 0b05:18f3 class-ID: 0300 serial: <filter>
  Hub-15: 8-0:1 info: Super-speed hub ports: 4 rev: 3.1 speed: 10 Gb/s
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0003 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-16: 9-0:1 info: Hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 4 rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-17: 9-1:2 info: Terminus FE 2.1 7-port Hub ports: 7 rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s power: 100mA chip-ID: 1a40:0201 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 9-1.1:4 info: Sunplus Innovation Gaming mouse [Philips SPK9304]
    type: Mouse driver: hid-generic,usbhid interfaces: 1 rev: 2.0 speed: 1.5 Mb/s
    power: 98mA chip-ID: 1bcf:08a0 class-ID: 0301
  Device-2: 9-1.5:6 info: Microdia Backlit Gaming Keyboard
    type: Keyboard,Mouse driver: hid-generic,usbhid interfaces: 2 rev: 2.0
    speed: 12 Mb/s power: 400mA chip-ID: 0c45:652f class-ID: 0301
  Device-3: 9-1.6:7 info: HUION H420 type: Mouse,HID driver: uclogic,usbhid
    interfaces: 3 rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s power: 100mA chip-ID: 256c:006e
    class-ID: 0300
  Hub-18: 9-1.7:8 info: Terminus Hub ports: 4 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
    power: 100mA chip-ID: 1a40:0101 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 9-2:3 info: Microdia USB 2.0 Camera type: Video,Audio
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo interfaces: 4 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
    power: 500mA chip-ID: 0c45:6367 class-ID: 0102 serial: <filter>
  Device-2: 9-4:11 info: VKB-Sim © Alex Oz 2021 VKBsim Gladiator EVO L
    type: HID driver: hid-generic,usbhid interfaces: 1 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s
    power: 500mA chip-ID: 231d:0201 class-ID: 0300
  Hub-19: 10-0:1 info: Super-speed hub ports: 4 rev: 3.1 speed: 10 Gb/s
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0003 class-ID: 0900
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 38.0 C mobo: 41.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): fan-1: 702 fan-2: 747 fan-3: 938 fan-4: 889 fan-5: 3132
    fan-6: 0 fan-7: 0
  GPU: device: nvidia screen: :0.0 temp: 49 C fan: 0% device: radeon
    temp: 53.0 C
Info:
  Processes: 842 Uptime: 3h 11m wakeups: 0 Init: systemd v: 252
  default: graphical tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: 12.2.1 alt: 10/11
  clang: 15.0.7 Packages: 2158 pm: pacman pkgs: 2110 libs: 495 tools: pamac,yay
  pm: flatpak pkgs: 31 pm: snap pkgs: 17 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16
  running-in: yakuake inxi: 3.3.25
```

Comment: duration of video 00:00:29.934000000, so `-ss 29.9`

Comment: Oh, good point, that routine was written assuming large video sizes. If you post that as your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Try removing `-huffman` and keep `optimal` or remove `-huffman optimal` and use `image2pipe` instead of `image2` then it should work regardless of `-ss` duration.

Comment: Changing `image2` to `image2pipe` didn't appear to help given that the length is 29.9s of video with a requested 30s `-ss`. *shrug*, which I suppose is reasonable. I'll just add a routine that checks the length.